# WPF different screen resolution settings?

Tags: wpf

Been looking around on the internet and I think more people talk about docking images etc... to the screen. What I am looking for is that I want the images and everything else on the page to stretch or shrink depending on the persons resolution?

I Havant set my screen to a height or width, I just set the screen to maximise on page load but this doesn't seem to work?

Does anyone have a solutions on this i am using a WPF Application.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work. This is a strange question because WPF is resolution independent.

Comment: @Sheridan what I mean is when I open this application on different resolutions I want the images and other content to scale to the their screen size. Dockpanals don't scale and neither do Stackpanals. I am asking what can I do to make them scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your controls below the Window in a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That will scale your whole window content.

Comment: I'm going have a go at this now and ill let you know of any problems. EDIT - Do i have to wrap all the different elements in a 1 view box or in all different ones?

Comment: Everything inside the `ViewBox` will be scaled to the same degree... if you use multiple `ViewBox`es, then their content will likely be scaled to different degrees.

Comment: @Sheridan I see what you mean, thanks for your time. When using a view box do I have to specify a Height and Width of my Window or not?

Answer (score 1):

While the `ViewBox` control is good for resizing UI elements, there is a preferable way to achieve the same goal. UIs in WPF are generally created using `Grid` controls. These enable developers to take advantage of the resizing abilities that they provide. Virtually all 'fit to size' applications use `Grid` elements.

When using `Grid` elements with the objective of filling all of the available space, there are a few things that you should consider. You generally shouldn't use exact widths and/or heights, instead using the `"Auto"` setting. Also, you must have at least one column and/or width dimension set to `"*"`... this will take up *all of the remaining space*:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Top left" Background="LightSeaGreen" Padding="20" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Bottom left" Background="LightBlue" Padding="20" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Top right" Background="LightGreen" Padding="20" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Bottom left" Background="LightCoral" Padding="20" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to help me out. I am going to give this a go now and hopefully I can get my application working.

Comment: Hello, just got back to my computer and I have tested your code out on a new project. I think you misunderstood me, there you have docked the different colours, I am looking so if I dragged your screen out the writing would get bigger as I am making the screen bigger, meaning if I open my application on a small resolution 1024x768 (my screen is 900x1600) that everything on my application will shrink to the size to that screen.

Comment: That will make an unusual application design, but if that's what you want, then I would recommend that you use @nvoigt's idea of using a `ViewBox`.